# How do I import for all classes in a scala package simultaneously?

Tags: scala, import, package

Consider package com.example . Inside package com.example we have two classes named Foo and Bar.

There is also an object named Baz located in a package named com.other . Is there a way I can import Baz to Foo and Bar using only one import statement? In other words, how can I define a block of imports that affects all classes (Foo and Bar) in a package (com.example)?

I tried the following, but it is not working.

```
// filename:package.scala location:com/example
package com { 
  package object example {
    import other.Baz
  }
}

// filename:Foo.scala location:com/example
package com.example {
  class Foo { 
    // Baz should be in scope here
    Baz.methodCall()
  }
  class Bar {
    // Baz should be in scope here too
    Baz.methodCall()
  }
}
```

I tried searching extensively, but I'm not sure how to phrase this scenario. Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried, in `Foo.scala`, `import package.com.example._`?

Comment: did you really mean to use a `package object`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding it to a `val`.

```
package com { 
  package object example {
    val Baz = other.Baz
  }
}
```

If you don't want `Baz` to be visible to the outside:

```
package com { 
  package object example {
    private[example] val Baz = other.Baz
  }
}
```